# lsof outputs greater than ulimit -Hn

Tags: linux, ulimit, lsof

The following commands run in a single session shows **lsof** size greater than **ulimit** supported size. How is this possible?

```
$ lsof | wc -l
226863
$ ulimit -n
200000
$ ulimit -Hn
200000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really on-topic here, but the answer is simple. `lsof` lists all open files systemwide. `ulimit` shows the limit for one shell session.

Comment: Sorry, somehow i did not think about it.